# Mutex lock halts program in mingw but not on linux

Tags: c++, mingw, mutex

I'm trying to port a prototype onto windows using mingw-w64, but am confused how it deals with threads. The following code stops after I lock a mutex.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>

int main() {
    std::mutex mu;
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mu);
    std::cout<<"starting"<<std::endl;
    mu.lock();
    std::cout<<"end"<<std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output should be

```
starting
end
```

but it only prints starting then hangs.

I tried the same program on linux and it works fine.

Here's my g++ version if it helps

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\g++.exe
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.2.1/lto-wrapper.exe
Target: x86_64-w64-mingw32
Configured with: ../gcc-8-20181214/configure --prefix=/mingw64 --with-local-prefix=/mingw64/local --build=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --host=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --target=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --with-native-system-header-dir=/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include --libexecdir=/mingw64/lib --enable-bootstrap --with-arch=x86-64 --with-tune=generic --enable-languages=ada,c,lto,c++,objc,obj-c++,fortran --enable-shared --enable-static --enable-libatomic --enable-threads=posix --enable-graphite --enable-fully-dynamic-string --enable-libstdcxx-filesystem-ts=yes --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --disable-libstdcxx-pch --disable-libstdcxx-debug --disable-isl-version-check --enable-lto --enable-libgomp --disable-multilib --enable-checking=release --disable-rpath --disable-win32-registry --disable-nls --disable-werror --disable-symvers --with-libiconv --with-system-zlib --with-gmp=/mingw64 --with-mpfr=/mingw64 --with-mpc=/mingw64 --with-isl=/mingw64 --with-pkgversion='Rev1, Built by MSYS2 project' --with-bugurl=https://sourceforge.net/projects/msys2 --with-gnu-as --with-gnu-ld
Thread model: posix
gcc version 8.2.1 20181214 (Rev1, Built by MSYS2 project)
```

Comment: Why do you lock the mutex a second time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot lock a mutex that is locked. It produces a dealock with undefined behavior.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/mutex/mutex/lock/

> If the mutex is currently locked by the same thread calling this function, it produces a deadlock (with undefined behavior). See recursive_mutex for a mutex type that allows multiple locks from the same thread.

Comment: I found this to cause the problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

To be able to lock a mutex several times, you should use `std::recursive_mutex` rather than `std::mutex`.

Also note that you should pair each `lock()` call with an `unlock()` call.